# C# copying byte array is being skipped over

Tags: c#, arrays

```
public byte[] CropImage(byte[] bmp, Rectangle cropSize, int stride)
{ 
    //make a new byte array the size of the area of cropped image
    int totalSize = cropSize.Width * 3 * cropSize.Height;
    int totalLength = bmp.Length;
    int startingPoint = (stride * cropSize.Y) + cropSize.X * 3;
    byte[] croppedImg = new byte[totalSize];

    //for the total size of the old array
    for(int y = 0; y<totalLength; y+= stride)
    {
        //copy a row of pixels from bmp to croppedImg
        Array.Copy(bmp, startingPoint + y, croppedImg, y, cropSize.Width*3);            
    }

    return croppedImg;
}
```

`Array.Copy` is being skipped over and not copying anything.

I thought maybe I made a mistake, but even when copying each byte manually it does the same thing.

This function takes in a raw BGR image byte array[] and crops it based on Rect(x, y, width, height).

Finally returning the cropped byte array to the main function.

Comment: What does "being skipped" mean? Did you try setting breakpoints, stepping through the code and inspecting your variables?

Comment: The problem is most probably within the image copying logic and not with `Array.Copy`. What does the `stride` parameter represent?

Comment: Also, why are you doing this logic by hand? I am almost sure that there are APIs within the .NET framework to do that work for you.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, I've tried setting breakpoints.  In the inspector it shows croppedImg[0,0,0,0,0,0]  and stepping through just returns a blank array size= totalSize

Comment: @YacoubMassad stride represents the stride of the original byte[] bmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
for(int y = 0; y<totalLength; y+= stride)
{
    //copy a row of pixels from bmp to croppedImg
    Array.Copy(bmp, startingPoint + y, croppedImg, y, cropSize.Width*3);            
}
```

you pass `y` to `Array.Copy` method argument which is supposed to be a `destinationIndex`, which is not true in your case.

In order to avoid such mistakes, use better names for your variables (and use more variables, they are cheap). For instance, the code could be like this

```
public byte[] CropImage(byte[] source, Rectangle cropRect, int sourceStride)
{
    int targetStride = cropRect.Width * 3;
    var target = new byte[cropRect.Height * targetStride];
    int sourcePos = cropRect.Y * sourceStride + cropRect.X * 3;
    int targetPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < cropRect.Height; i++)
    {
        Array.Copy(source, sourcePos, target, targetPos, targetStride);
        sourcePos += sourceStride;
        targetPos += targetStride; 
    }
    return target;
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that.  You're right targetPos should increment by the targetStride not he sourceStride.    Thank you!